# Find first ancestor to be a child of an object with specific class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a correct way to find elements first ancestor to be a child of an element with a specific class.

Using XPath notation I'm looking for (if I didn't botch it):

```
./ancestor::*[../@class='my_class']
```

I guess I can run a while(...) loop calling parent() until current elements parent has specified class and go from there, but maybe there is some selector/filter/whatever in jQuery that can be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you're trying to get the last ancestor when going up, before hitting the ancestor with '.my_class':

```
$(element).parentsUntil('.my_class').last()
```

[See documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/)

Comment: Yes, parentsUntil is apparently what I wanted :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery find a child with specific class :

```
$("mycontrol").find(".myclass");
```

find parent with specific class :

```
$("mycontrol").closest(".myclass"); //return the first parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
jQuery(".my_class").parent().eq(0)
```

If I have this right.. First parent that is a child of an element with class "my_class":

Answer (score 0):

Find all the elements with class `.my-class` and get the set of their children, then use `.closest()`
on your jQuery object, with that set as an argument.

```
$('myElementSelector').closest($('.my-class').children())
```

I think that should do it...